to Both of you, or to you both
A friend of mine got married,I want to congratulate them but I got confused which sentence is correct  Or more appropriate.
1.Congratulations to both of you.
2.Congratulations to you both.

Both are correct; Neither is more (or less) appropriate.

This question is similar to: Which is correct? "Happy new year to both of you" or "Happy new year to you both". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As heard in a song by The Smiths, 'the both of you' is mainly UK regional dialect.

Both are valid. To you both is more common though the gap between that and to both of you is closing in these recent years.
